# Bash script -ne comparison giving "command not found" error

Tags: bash, ssh

In my bash script I wish to ssh into a machine, and if the machine is down, perform something within an if statement.

To check whether or not the the machine is down I have an if statement using the -ne command which I use to compare the value returned by the ssh function ($? which is 255 if the ssh was unsuccessful) and 0.

However I get the following error

```
line 5: [0: command not found
```

Here is my code

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh blobbby

if [0 -ne $?]
then
    echo "ssh not succesful"
fi
```

If someone can please explain what mistake I've made I would be most grateful.

Comment: This is the same question with lots of in depth answers 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468824/command-not-found-when-attempting-integer-equality-in-bash#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A space character must follow the opening bracket and precede the closing one.